# Selectable circle on a selectableItemBackgroundBorderless widget is truncated

Tags: android, android-view, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles, android-background

I am trying the new `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` background on Android Lollipop to create a circle selector. So far the result looks good, as the picture below. The circle even extends over the "2" and "4" bounds. However the circle is truncated at several sides (top and left at the picture).

Why is it so, and how to make the circle complete?

[image: truncated circle]

Comment: Ripples are projected onto the first available background of an ancestor view, which in this case is either a gray or transparent background on the layout containing the key views. Remove the background from the layout containing the key pad.

Comment: @alanv thank you! although this seems undocumented, your answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try applying the `android:clipChildren="false"` attribute to the layout containing the keypad layout? By default it is `true` and prevents child animations from playing beyond the child's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have set background attribute like
`android:background=?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`

Just change code with `android:foreground=?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`. It will make a rectangle ripple effect, not a circle.